# String not Delimiting when the delimiter mentioned is encountered

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file which I am parsing using a for loop. I am also mentioning a delimiter as I want to separate the text when the delimiter is encountered. It works for all the lines accept one. Below are the lines

```
####################################################################################################
# Directory structure
####################################################################################################

DIRLIST         := $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
```

I am using this code

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims=$(APPLICATION_PATH) " %%a in (test.txt) do (

set part1=%%a

echo part1 = !part1!
pause
)
```

Comment: to use delayed expansion, use `echo part1 = !part1!`

Comment: i did try using and modified my code but i still get the line DIRLIST         := $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\        <code> Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims=$(APPLICATION_PATH) " %%a in (..\..\..\Make\path_settings.mak) do (
 
 set part1=%%a
 echo part1 = !part1! 
 pause
) </code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for` command, `delims` clause is used to indicate the list of characters that will be used as delimiters. In your case, for the posted data, the delimiter should be the closing parenthesis, with two tokens, the first one the text on the left or the delimiter and the second one the text on the right of the delimiter

```
@echo off
setLocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=)" %%a in (..\..\..\Make\path_settings.mak) do (
    if not "%%b"=="" echo(%%b
)
```

The two tokens are only necessary if inside the line a second closing parenthesis could exists, so the `*` in the `token` clause will ensure it will be included in the data retrieved. But this means that lines that does not include a parenthesis will retrieve all its data into `%%a` and nothing in `%%b`, so the `if` condition is necessary.

If there is no second parenthesis, then the code can be simplified to

```
@echo off
setLocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=)" %%a in (..\..\..\Make\path_settings.mak) do (
    echo(%%a
)
```

**edited** to reflect execution of the command

```
[M:\]:# type test.txt
####################################################################################################
# Directory structure
####################################################################################################

DIRLIST         := $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\
                   $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\

[M:\]:# type test.cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=)" %%a in (test.txt) do (
        echo %%a
    )


[M:\]:# test.cmd
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
/test/app/model\
[M:\]:#
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion caused, the ones in parenthesis are comments

Comment: @SandeepBhat, I am rereading the question and my answer and there is a thing i don't see clear. Exactly what should be the final output?

Comment: Sorry again, the output i require is                                /test/app/model\                                                    /test/app/model\                                                    /test/app/model\                                                    /test/app/model\

Comment: /test/app/model\ from each line

Comment: @SandeepBhat, then any of the two included codes should work. Are not headers needed?

Comment: headers are not required. Yes the code should work but it only doesnt work for the very first line that is DIRLIST         := $(APPLICATION_PATH)/test/app/model\

Comment: @SandeepBhat, no, I've tested both codes against your input data and output seven lines with the text after the first `)`

Comment: ok i have just edited the question to avoid confusion, the () were used for comments.

Comment: @SandeepBhat, It is the same data I'm testing against. And both codes in my answer dump the string after the first `)`, that is `/test/app/model\ ` seven times, the same number that in input file. Isn't it the right behaviour?

Comment: yes it right, i wonder why it isnt working for me, i put that text in a test.txt file and also changed my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65579/discussion-between-mc-nd-and-sandeep-bhat).

Comment: my company restricts the page :(

Comment: @SandeepBhat, This is what I'm doing (just to ensure both are doing the same). 1[ Copy your input file into a `test.txt` file ] 2[ copy the code in my answer (any of them) into `test.cmd` changing the file reference to `test.txt`] 3[ Execute `test.cmd` ] - And the output are seven identical lines. What is your output?

Comment: @SandeepBhat, this is not the output from the codes in my answer.

Comment: @SandeepBhat, I've included in the answer a copy/paste from my console. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually shouldn't work. The point is that delims can't be strings but chars. If you use a string each char will be regarded as a delim.

However, there is a workaround:

1. replace the string you want to act as a delim by a special cahr that won't be in your strings (e.g. @, |, etc.)
2. split your modified string using the special char

You can find an example here: http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=134599.0 Reply #3

Comment: correct. Besides that, `tokens=*` overrides `delims=...` and you get the whole line

Comment: @Stephan, the override is only partial. If the line starts with characters included in the `delims` clause they will be not included in the retrieved data.